# new installation stopped conncecting to wifi, but asking the password

Tags: wireless, broadcom, connection

Yesterday I did a new installation for my old laptop. I can access the internet via cable, yesterday I was able to access the wifi. Now I see the wifi
but I am not able to connect since the network manager keeps asking for the password.

Some extra notes:

- Wifi works on my phone, the password has been checked.
- When the problem occurred, I had also two network-manager icons in the task bar. Reading in internet this has been resolved.
- Already tried to do `sudo service network-manager restart` did not work.
- `sudo apt purge wl` and `sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer` was also ineffective.
- Turn on and of the wifi with F12 did not work.
- I rebooted several times to double check each attempt.
- Not clear to me why rfkill gives me 2 wireless LAN (see below)
- I installed Lubuntu, I am not sure why `lsb_release` shows Ubuntu below.

Below you can find some output of normal commands.

I am not really an expert, can anybody help me further?

```
ff-HP:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

```
ff-HP:~$ rfkill list all
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
@ff-HP:~$ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 02
       serial: 78:ac:c0:cc:a2:a1
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:17 ioport:6000(size=256) memory:f0010000-f0010fff memory:f0000000-f000ffff memory:f2500000-f251ffff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0b1
       version: 01
       serial: ac:81:12:42:9b:6e
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmsmac driverversion=5.0.0-37-generic firmware=610.812 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:19 memory:f1100000-f1103fff
```

```
@ff-HP:~$ sudo lshw -short
[sudo] password for xxx: 
H/W path         Device      Class       Description
====================================================
                             system      HP Pavilion G62 Notebook PC (XF328EA#UUZ)
/0                           bus         143C
/0/0                         memory      1MiB BIOS
/0/23                        memory      4GiB System Memory
/0/23/0                      memory      2GiB DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1334 MHz (0.7 ns)
/0/23/1                      memory      2GiB DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1334 MHz (0.7 ns)
/0/2c                        processor   AMD Phenom(tm) II N620 Dual-Core Processor
/0/2c/2d                     memory      256KiB L1 cache
/0/2c/2e                     memory      2MiB L2 cache
/0/100                       bridge      RS880 Host Bridge
...
```

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please [don’t add “SOLVED” to the title](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7413/250300). In order to mark your question _solved_ in the right way, you may [_accept_ the answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) (by clicking on the tick mark (✓) next to it) that helped you. In case the [helpful answer was posted by you](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer), you'll have to wait 2 days before being able to accept it.

Comment: _“I installed Lubuntu, I am not sure why lsb_release shows Ubuntu below.”_ This is not a problem. Lubuntu is just a [flavour of Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours). This means it has a different desktop environment (GUI) but the command-line part is the same.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is solved.

I updated to Lubuntu 19.04 and the problem persisted. 
Than I performed a `sudo service network-manager restart` and after rebooting I was able to connect to the wifi normally.